# SSRS line chart

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have one question to the line chart.
I would like to create a line chart, which values are given. It should look like this chart here: 
[image]

My question is, how can I implement this. I tried to put it as a stripline in the chart but it only shows a horizontal line without this steps at the beginning.
How can I create this line chart like in the picture above?

can I put into this:
[image]

the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Striplines are intended to display just a line across the chart, or varying width, height, to demonstrate an area... [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239316.aspx)

> Strip lines, or strips, are horizontal or vertical ranges that shade the background of the chart in regular or custom intervals

To get the behaviour (I think) you require you can add a new series to the data you are returning with each of those datapoints.  Irrespective of what other data you are charting, you can change the type of this series to Line Chart, and change the order of the series on teh chart to make it uppoermost.

Without further information - such as the data you are tyrying to superimpose this on - it's hard to advise further.

Comment: can I put into the expression field several values, to show the line like above?

Comment: You want your new series to be reporting against a column from your dataset of target values, surely?  Why would you be setting these values in the report only?

Comment: could you maybe show me an example. I tried it but it not works